# Switching from http to https. Invalid certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https, afnetworking

I have an app that connects to my home routers web interface. I want to convert this to use https instead of just http.
I was originally using `ASIHttpRequest`, but as it's no longer supported i'm switching over to `AFNetworking`.
The problem is, whenever I try to connect, I get this **error** message:

```
_block_invoke_0220 [Line 243] ERROR: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.1.1” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x9792ad0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.1.1/Info.live.htm, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.1.1/Info.live.htm, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.1.1” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0xa6a3560 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.1.1” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=< SecTrustRef:
```

If I navigate to the url i safari, I get a message that Safari can't verify the identity.... and I have to click continue to carry on.
How can I achieve this? I don't really know anything about ssl or https unfortunately.
Here is the code i'm currently using:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://192.168.1.1/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// Set authorization
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:user password:pass];

NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"Info.live.htm" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responceString = [operation responseString];
    //        NSLog(@"%@",responceString);
    if ([self parseInfoLive:responceString])
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloadsComplete" object:nil];
}
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error.description);
                                 }];


[operation start];
```

Comment: The certificate obviously is not trusted in conjunction with the host you are submitting. You will have to disable the validity check to get this working - *warning* do not submit such app to the App Store but only use such solution for your development phase.

Comment: Thanks. How do I disable the validity check? I've tried adding #define AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES 1 to the top of the code.

Comment: Also, if you say not to submit the app like that, what would be a solution to make the certificate trusted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For getting around the validity check of the host certificate, add the following code.

First add an interface for the setter method that is already within the SDK but not exposed into public:

```
@interface NSURLRequest(Private)
+(void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)inAllow forHost:(NSString *)inHost;
@end
```

Now, whenever you are rendering a new request, invoke that setter:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[inURL host]];
```

**Warning**

**Do not use this code for production but only while developing your app in cases where the certificate is not yet approved/submitted/installed. Typical would be the use of a development server that does not have a trusted certificate installed.
The use of this code will get your App rejected from distribution via iTunes as it uses a private API method.**

For making sure that things work smoothly in a production environment, you will have to get a trusted SSL certificate for your host. There are various authoritative companies providing such thing. To mention at least one (there are MANY more), you could use [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/compare/gdcompare2_ssl.aspx?isc=sslfgeu16&currencytype=EUR&ef_id=UFXZawAARXb7hA9W:20120916135139%3as).

---

Update (31st May 2013)

[AFNetworking got updated](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/204) to support invalid certificates out of the box, without using any private API's. Kudos to Peter Steinberger!

For enabling that feature, the most convenient solution is to add the following to your prefix header (.pch):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
#endif
```

Once again, I can not emphasize enough that you should refrain from enabling that feature in production code - you would pretty much invalidate the entire point of SSL connections and render them vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks. That works now. I guess i'll have to speak to those that requested this to see if they have valid certificates.

Comment: Is it possible to add the self-signed certificate to the app that you can accept when you navigate to the url using safari?

Comment: You should refrain from using self-signed certificates in a production environment. Use a properly accepted certificate, it is really not that hard or expensive.

Comment: The problem is, my app connects to the users servers. So they'd need their own on their server. But the servers do have a self-signed one as default.

Comment: That indeed is a challenge. I do not know how you could circumvent the certificate validation in an iTunes accepted way. Using the code above will get you rejected as it uses a private API method.

Comment: An answer that shows the public API to use to handle a self-signed certificate can be found here: [I want to ignore certificate verification, where and how to do it with XMLRPC web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916574/i-want-to-ignore-certificate-verification-where-and-how-to-do-it-with-xmlrpc-we/3918268#3918268)

Comment: Thanks. That link led me to a few different things to try. 1, Cocoanetics suggests a way to bypass cert checking for a specific domain. 2, GDS blog suggests you can add a self cert certificate to the Trusted certs on a device by emailing it to yourself. I wonder if I can ship it with an app and have it install?

Comment: @JayO'Conor that certainly is a better way when using NSURLConnection. The question however was referring to the use of AFNetworking and not NSURLConnection.

Comment: @Till AFNetworking is built on top of NSURLConnection. AFURLConnectionOperation implements NSURLConnection delegate method -connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: AFNetworking provides AFURLConnectionOperation -setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock: which is pretty much just a block wrapper around the NSURLConnection delegate method.

Comment: @Ross : Where to include "interface NSURLRequest" code?

Comment: FYI: Using a GoDaddy cert will unfortunately not resolve this issue, as they are not trusted by iOS. The user would have to open the domain in Safari and trust the certificate there before the connection will work in the app.

Answer (score 1):

This URL from Apple documentation might help [Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html)

In the above document read Introduction section.
[image: Screenshot for Apple document]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with AFNetworking, but there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i/15074358#15074358) that works around the error you are seeing.  Till's answer is reputed to keep you from being able to submit your app to the app store.

Comment: That quoted solution does not use AFNetworking, hence it does not answer the question.