# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 iPhone

Tags: iphone, linkedin-api

I am getting the following error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.linkedin.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x1c53e630

This works fine on simulator but on device it is giving above mentioned error.

Please help to rectify it.

Comment: have u tring to find this with some effort in google take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916574/i-want-to-ignore-certificate-verification-where-and-how-to-do-it-with-xmlrpc-we and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Comment: i tried above links , but not worth for me ,

Comment: I got it by losting my whole day, It was my device setting that need to change the date and time , and set it automatically ON for current time zone .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is device setting that need to change the date and time , and set it automatically ON for current time zone .

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
  [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

 [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Hope it helpful

Comment: i have already tried it, this is throwing same error as i mentioned in question, it is working fine on simulator, this error is killing me on device only.

Comment: Improve on this answer by explaining what the solution would fix, perhaps format for readability.

Comment: I got it by losting my whole day, It was my device setting that need to change the date and time , nad set it automatically ON for current time zone .

Comment: you should give credit when you copy code like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823)