# iOS Can't perform HTTP GET request -Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012

Tags: ios, http, get

I am trying to perform a HTTP Get request, but I keep on getting Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012  error. MY code is :

```
@try {
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://api.mintchat.com/agent/chats/", agentSecret];

    NSLog(@"******Agents Active List URL Str - %@", url);
    NSURL *nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];  
    NSLog(@"******Agents Active List URL - %@", nsUrl);

   // Make the request, returning a JSON response, just as a plain old string.
   //NSData *jsonDataString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:API_ID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-ID"];
    [request setValue:API_SECRET forHTTPHeaderField:@"X­-API-­SECRET"];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response Code %d", [response statusCode]);
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {
        NSString *responseData = [ [NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"Response  ==> %@", responseData);        
    } else {
       if (error)
          NSLog(@"ERror : %@", error);
    }
}@catch(NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception - %@", e);
   }
```

I am to get response in JSon, but as things are not working so we are trying with some normal response. I confirmed the Headers to be added to the request. I need to add the both values to the headers. The url is also proper.

The results/logs I get is :
Response Code 0

> Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
>       (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x8abf470 {
>       NSErrorFailingURLKey=.......NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=......NSUnderlyingError=0x8dafed0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"
>       }

I also searched a lot on net reg this error, bit couldn't get any substantial help. I also confirmed regarding access to the web server api. With other url also I get the same results. From 3 urls, I could achieve results of 1st url using POST, but those other 2 urls - just could't get thru it.

Can anyone please help me with this problem. Where am going wrong ? Why can't access the api's. 
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415157/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1202-iphone

Comment: Note to future visitors: this is not actually a duplicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is **NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication**

> Returned when an asynchronous request for authentication is cancelled
>   by the user. This is typically incurred by clicking a “Cancel” button
>   in a username/password dialog, rather than the user making an attempt
>   to authenticate.

It means you need authentication to access the resource which you are trying to access w/o signing your request properly (wrong agentSecret or API_ID or API_SECRET)

Comment: Got the solution from your error. Required to use NSURLRequest instead of NSMutableRequest, hence added headers to mutRequest & made a copy of it to request. And the original problem - In header fields, in place of '-' in X­-API-­SECRET, unicode value was being sent thru the request so it was X\u000API\u000SECRET; thus it wasn't being authenticated and was getting failed. Added those header keys & values in instance vars, corrected the request factor & thus was able to access the api successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

You may get this error while hitting a HTTPS (not HTTP) URL with a bad/expired certificate with AFNetworking. (Chrome shows the "Your connection is not private" message when hitting the URL).

Comment: Ok, this is a correct answer. But what to do with status code 0?

Answer (score 4):

For my case i just set Yes for following flag of afnetworking http client. allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES, it starts working for https get request.

Comment: I am having a similar situation here. It works after I switch not to use HTTPS.

Comment: that is correct if you use http instead of https, but actually we need to have valid self sign certificate and need to set HTTPClient.defaultSSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModePublicKey;

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, you will get this error whenever a server sends back a `401` (unauthorized) status code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

just paste these lines in info-list