# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate, nsmutableurlrequest, nserror

I am getting the following error when running my code from the xcode.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x17166b740
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://..../move/resource/v1/user/me/activity/summary?start_date=2015-01-21&end_date=2015-01-14&detail=true,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x17405b630 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)",
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://..../move/resource/v1/user/me/activity/summary?start_date=2015-01-21&end_date=2015-01-14&detail=true}

Here is my Code

```
  NSString *urlSummaryString = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@summary?start_date=%@&end_date=%@&detail=true", kMisfitCloudEndpoint, strStartDate,strEndDate] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    __block NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    __block NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlSummaryString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
    [request setValue:@"access_token" forHTTPHeaderField:self.misfitAccessToken];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if(connectionError){
            // Handle the connection error
            return ;
        }}];
```

Can any one help me what is wrong here. Is it something related to SSL Certificate on the server and is related to the security. When I use CocoaRestClient to make my request it works perfectly.

Can some body explain me in detail what cause this problem or if any body can have the solution for this. I have to use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest]` method. I am using `Xcode` 6.1 and `ios` 8.1.2

Comment: You have tried to use NSURLRequest instead of NSMutableURLReques? I think your error is **NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication**. Look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111801/ios-cant-perform-http-get-request-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1012

Comment: i have to add header and GET method to the URLRequest thats why i have to use MSMutableURLRequest. I did not get you point.

Comment: Check that before you make the call the access_token param is enhanced

Comment: Try to restart your simulator.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i am making a very silly mistake.

```
[request setValue:self.misfitAccessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token" ];
```

This solved my problem

Comment: I am facing same problem when i do not set Access Token, but when i set the access token in header every thing work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This is **kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication** error,
-10xx errors are of the **CFNetworkErrors** enum.
Name of this constant is pretty selfexplanatory. Server cancelled authentication for some reason